# How to map List<Guid> to List<Class> using Automapper?

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

```
public class A {
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
}

public class B {
    public List<Guid> People { get; set; }
}

CreateMap<B, A>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.People, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => ?));
```

Error - AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Guid -> Person

Comment: You need a mapping rule to map from `Guid` to `Person`. `CreateMap<Guid, Person>().ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));`

Answer (score 0):

Since the list's data type is custom class (`Person`), the second mapping configuration is required.

```
CreateMap<B, A>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.People, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.People));

CreateMap<Guid, Person>()
    . // Here define your map of how to create a Person object from Guid.
```